# PHP – pass more than one query over a source file

Tags: php

I have a basic web page with a number of buttons that use PHP to query a CSV table.
Each button has it’s own PHP file behind it.

What each button/PHP does: If a row on the CSV contains a string, the row is echoed to the screen. So for example button 1 will display a list of records where column X contains string Y.

My question is, if the user wants to run multiple queries (a mix of queries at the same time), 
what are my options? I guess one option is to output the query results to a temp file and run each consecutive query on the file, re-writing it each time. But I’m just wondering if there’s any “quick and easy” way.  MySQL is not an option on this one. 
Below is the meat of the code anyway... thanks!

```
$file = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");  //open the file

...

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE){  //read through the file

...

foreach ($line as $elt) {     



...

if ($line[X] == "myString") {  // check column location X at each record for myString

echo "table border=..."; //clean up the output with some basic html rendering

echo $line[N]; //N will be the contents of a cell, print to screen
...
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean by "multiple queries"? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that.

Comment: You said MySQL is not an option but how about [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)? If you're working with files maybe you can create an SQLite database to create a query with a Join and multiple criteria...

Comment: "multiple queries": each button is one fixed query, e.g. if row X contains StringY then echo the row. But if the user wanted to exercise a query that was effectively 2 or more buttons, e.g. if row X contains StringY AND if row Z contains some other string etc.

Comment: MySQL/ SQLite etc makes allot of sense of course. I was just hoping there was a quick option here, without doing allot of re-coding. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
if ($line[X] == "myString")
```

with

```
if (in_array($line[X], $myQueries))
```

But the question is how is the query or "myString" currently passed into the script?

That would impact how $myQueries  - an array of the queries - would be generated.

Comment: How the query currently passed, yep good question. A php is called from a html button, which passes a variable via html post. Not the most elegant answer here but I think a "quick and easy" answer is to use a html form to pass multiple queries, and in the php use the variables in an IF X AND Y AND etc... statement.